# How to Save ,Load or Use learned data? When using Keras Audio Learning Machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am making sound cognition machine learning program like amazon alexa
(Of course i cannot make such like that..just can hear "on/off" sound) 
i want to use my learned data in other program...
Program A is the Machine learning program by using dataset On/OFF

And i don't know how to use this data in real program

```
(Load Model Code)
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('Sound_model.h5')
```

I Only know Save/Load But i cannot adjust this model to my program..
How can i compare my voice and this data and make a result by this?

I am using MFCC method to encoding. So the real voice also do this.